# Best way to structure scalable Heroku flask web application and it's workers for python

Tags: python, heroku, flask

*BTW. I'm using Flask.*

So, when the user requests a specific url for ex. `example.com/specificshit`  I need  to retrieve various APIs, compute stats from them, get them back to the user and store it somewhere for later use. As I understand, the problem with straightforward approach would be that this would leave the use hanging for quite sometime until all the calculations are done. As far as I've read I should use workers processes which should be even easier on heroku. But how do I return the result to the user after I calculate them?

Seems that my newbie @python status is really holding me back here as there seems to be so many things I have to set up and I just can't get it right. So what are good and simple ways to structure something like this so that the app remains scalable if needed? Sorry for the long rant and thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what you're asking about here is queueing.

Here's the best way to do what you're talking about:

- Use a queueing broker like [Amazon SQS](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/) or [Rabbit MQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) with Celery.
- When a user visits your page that requires a lot of calculations, accept the incoming request, tell celery to run a task asynchronously, then render an HTML page to the user immediately.
- The user will then see an HTML page, which should typically have some sort of spinner on it to let the user know calculations are being done.
- When you previously told celery to run your task, what it did was it fired off a message into SQS / RabbitMQ.
- You'll then have a worker process running on Heroku which receives the message from SQS / RabbitMQ, and runs a function to do your calculations.
- Once those calculations are complete, this function will store the calculated data in either a database, or will just return a response to the message broker somewhere.
- You'll then either: have some AJAX code on your browser poll for this data via a private URL (/calculations/results/xxx or something), or use something like websockets to push this data directly to the web browser from your server.